# Is it possible to use Yup to validate ES6 Sets directly?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, yup

Is it possible to use Yup to validate ES6 Sets directly?

My intention is to use something like:

`const schema = yup.set().of( yup.string() ).min(1).required()`

Is there any way to use yup so that I could enforce those validation requirements?

Comment: It doesn't look like it right now out of the box. What you can do, however, is [create a new type](https://github.com/jquense/yup#extending-schema-types) (scroll to the bottom)

Answer (score 1):

I decided to tack on additional function to array()

```
yup.addMethod( yup.array, 'set', function() {
    return this.transform(function(value, originalValue){
        if ( this.isType( value ))
            return value;

        return [...originalValue]
    })
})
```

so that I could do something like this:

`yup.array().set().ensure().of( yup.string() ).min(1).required(),`

Not the best solution, but it's working fine for now, I'd probably do a proper class declaration to extends yup.array later on in the near future, if the needs arise.

Thanks!